# when i try to del multiple selected rows; only few r deleted not all

Tags: java, swing

When I print `rowcount` on clicking delete button, it prints some arbitrary value. I am using a table model which is created by me as `dt`. It prints some large arbitrary values. Please help to correct this code.

```
/*
 * UpdateGymFees.java
 *
 * Created on Sep 21, 2012, 2:26:37 PM
 */
package gymmain;

import java.sql.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.swing.DefaultCellEditor;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.ListSelectionModel;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

/**
 *
 * @author sony
 */
public class UpdateGymFees extends javax.swing.JFrame implements Runnable {
    //String  r[] = new String [7];
    //String r1,r2,r3,r4,r5,r6;

    String b[] = new String[4];
    int v[] = new int[5];
    int c[] = new int[100];
    JComboBox c1 = new JComboBox();
    JComboBox c2 = new JComboBox();
    JComboBox c3 = new JComboBox();
    DefaultTableModel dt;
    DB data = new DB();
    Thread t1;

    /**
     * Creates new form UpdateGymFees
     */
    public UpdateGymFees() {

        setVisible(true);
        t1 = new Thread(this);
        t1.start();

        data.dbConnect();
        initComponents();
        jTable1.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
        jTable1.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.MULTIPLE_INTERVAL_SELECTION);
        String a[][] = new String[1000][1000];
        int i = 0;
        try {
            ResultSet rs1 = data.st.executeQuery("select * from UpdateGymFees");

            // Variables declaration - do not modify

    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser jDateChooser1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTable jTable1;
    // End of variables declaration

    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            try {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(MemberReg.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }
                for (int q = 0; q < jTable1.getRowCount(); q++) {
                    if (("" == null ? jTable1.getValueAt(q, 4).toString() != null : !"".equals(jTable1.getValueAt(q, 4).toString()))
                        && ("" == null ? jTable1.getValueAt(q, 5).toString() != null : !"".equals(jTable1.getValueAt(q, 5).toString()))
                        && ("" == null ? jTable1.getValueAt(q, 6).toString() != null : !"".equals(jTable1.getValueAt(q, 6).toString()))) {
                        int z = 4, y = 0;
                        while (z < 7) {
                            b[y] = jTable1.getValueAt(q, z).toString();
                            v[y] = Integer.parseInt(b[y]);
                            z++;
                            y++;
                        }
                        v[3] = v[1] - v[2] + v[0];
                        v[4] = v[1] + v[0];
                        b[3] = Integer.toString(v[3]);
                        jTable1.setValueAt(v[3], q, 7);
                        System.out.print(v[3]);
                    }
                }
            } catch (NullPointerException npe) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Edit*

The delete action code from the comments:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    System.out.println(jTable1.getRowCount());
    int c[] = jTable1.getSelectedRows();
    for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getSelectedRowCount(); i++) {
        try {
            dt.removeRow(c[i]);
            System.out.println(c[i]);
            System.out.println(jTable1.getSelectedRowCount());
        } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select the row to be deleted");
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: it prints 103232314103232314103232314103232314103232314103232314103232314103232314103232314103232314103232314103232314103232314103232314103232314103232314103232314103232314103232314103232314103232314103232314103232314103232

Comment: It would be better if you outline the portion of the code that you suspect is causing the problem. Also add brief description of what you're intended to achieve.

Comment: private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
System.out.println(jTable1.getRowCount());
int c[]=jTable1.getSelectedRows();
 for(int i=0; i< jTable1.getSelectedRowCount();i++ )
 { try{dt.removeRow(c[i]);
 System.out.println(c[i]);
    System.out.println(jTable1.getSelectedRowCount());}
   catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e)
 {
 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Select the row to be deleted");
 } 


 } i want to del the selected rows

Comment: Instead of justing values to the console, it might help you (and us) if you prefixed the out put with a meaningful message, such as "row count"

Comment: please edit your question with the additional info (instead of doing so in comments, which is quite unreadable)

Answer (score 4):

The problem with your delete action is that you delete the wrong rows:

```
 int c[]=jTable1.getSelectedRows(); 
 for(int i=0; i< jTable1.getSelectedRowCount();i++ ) { 
   try{
     dt.removeRow(c[i]);
```

You first store the indices of the rows in `c[]`, and then remove them one by one. But the moment you removed the first row, the remaining indices in `c[]` became invalid as the rowcount of the table has been changed. You either have to remove them all at once, or adjust your indices.

Further comments on the code you posted in your question:

- Database connections and accessing/modifying Swing components should not happen on the same `Thread`. Move your database operations to a background `Thread`. Consult the [concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) guide for more information
- Never-ever sleep on the Event Dispatch Thread (not sure whether your sleep is actually on the EDT, but since you are accessing swing components in that `Runnable` it should be on the EDT)
- What do you expect to happen with all those `"" == null` checks in your code. This will always evaluate to `false`
- I also doubt that the `jTable1.getValueAt(q, 4).toString() != null` calls will ever evaluate to `false`. That would mean you have a class where the `toString` method returns `null`, which would be very very weird. It is far more likely your `JTable` contains a `null` value, and in that case you already triggered the `NullPointerException` by calling `toString` on it
- All those `try-catch` statements for `RuntimeException`s (like `NullPointerException` and `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` are normally not needed. See the reasons mentioned above. If I encounter those in code, alarm bells go off and I try to figure out why that exception happened in the first place and avoid it, rather then catching it.

Comment: +1 Beat me to it, just popped into my head. Some nice suggestions